# CSS is breaking in vuejs on reload of page

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

when i reload the page the css is breaking in vuejs

[image]

I tried to change the css from my app.vue but nothing happened it is having the same problem..

Comment: please create minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this, you can use `v-cloak`. This directive is used to hide an element until the Vue instance has finished compiling. This is useful when dealing with dynamic content that is generated by the Vue instance, and we want to avoid any flickering or jumping of the page as the content is being loaded.
Check the [official docs](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-cloak).

```js
const app = Vue.createApp()

app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app[v-cloak] {
  display: none
}

section {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightcyan
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: yes now tried worked for me! thanks...

Comment: you can also add some loaders for better user experience. https://cssloaders.github.io/

Comment: yes its there already but Im using vue2 version...